# How to disable `is` special attribute of Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue JS `is` is a special attribute that can be used to dynamically load a component. As a result, Vue JS treats an element especially, if it has `is` attribute and try to load a component as per the value of the `is` attribute.

Now, I'm trying to implement Chrome's casting feature. I'm using [a minified script](https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1) from gstatic that searches for an element with query `button[is=google-cast-button]`. However, whenever I'm putting such a button in my component, Vue JS starts to treat this button especially and throws an error that **there is no such component named `google-cast-button`**.

For this reason, I need to disable Vue JS from treating `is` attribute especially and ignore whatever value it contains. I would prefer disabling this feature inside a particular component. However, if that is not possible, globally disabling this feature is okay too.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `v-bind:is.prop="'google-cast-button'"` might do?

Comment: If you don't need to use any other Vue template syntax for that button you might be able to use `v-pre`, https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre.

Comment: Please show us how you currently "put in" this button in your component. How does it look like ?

Comment: A custom directive that adds `is` attr may help.